# Why my php file doesn't recognize a session?

Tags: php, html, session

I have two files: a login file and a view file.
In the login.php file I start a session like this: “$_SESSION["who"] = $_POST["who"];”
When I press the login button, it redirects me to the view.php file. The view.php checks the session to see if the user's name is set and if the user's name is not present, the view.php must stop immediately using the PHP die() function.

My problem is that regardless if I put the user name or not, always uses the die() function.

This is my code for each file.
The login.php file:

```
session_start();

if ( isset($_POST['cancel'] ) ) {
    // Redirect the browser to game.php
    header("Location: index.php");
    return;
}

$salt = 'XyZzy12*_';
$stored_hash = '1a52e17fa899cf40fb04cfc42e6352f1';  // Pw is php123

$failure = false;  // If we have no POST data

// Check to see if we have some POST data, if we do process it
if ( isset($_POST['who']) && isset($_POST['pass']) ) {
    unset($_SESSION["who"]);
    if ( strlen($_POST['who']) < 1 || strlen($_POST['pass']) < 1 ) {
        $_SESSION["error"] = "User name and password are required";
        header( 'Location: login.php' ) ;
        return;
    } else {
        if (strpos($_POST['who'], '@') == false) {
            $_SESSION["error"] = "Email must have an at-sign @";
            header( 'Location: login.php' ) ;
            return; 
        } else {
                $check = hash('md5', $salt.$_POST['pass']);
            if ( $check == $stored_hash ) {
                $_SESSION["who"] = $_POST["who"];
                header( 'Location: view.php' ) ;
                return;
            } else {
                $_SESSION["error"] = "Incorrect password";
                header( 'Location: login.php' ) ;
                return; 
            }
        }
    }
}

// Fall through into the View
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php require_once "bootstrap.php"; ?>
<title>123</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h1>Please Log In</h1>
<?php
    if ( isset($_SESSION["error"]) ) {
        echo('<p style="color:red">'.htmlentities($_SESSION['error'])."</p>\n");
        unset($_SESSION["error"]);
    }
?>
<form method="POST">
<label for="who">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="who" id="who"><br/>
<label for="id_123">Password</label>
<input type="text" name="pass" id="id_1723"><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Log In">
<input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel">
</form>
<p>
For a password hint, view source and find a password hint
in the HTML comments.
<!-- Hint: The password is php (all lower case) followed by 123. -->
</p>
</div>
</body>
```

The view.php file:

```
<?php
if ( ! isset($_SESSION['who']) ) {
    die('Not logged in');
}
require_once "pdo.php";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>123</title>
<?php require_once "bootstrap.php"; ?>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h1>Tracking Autos for <?php ?> </h1>
<h2>Automobiles</h2>
<p><a href="add.php">Add New</a> | <a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should do `session_start();` in every file you want to have the session active

Comment: your view.php should have session_start() too at the beginning after your opening php tag "<?php"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put session_start(); at the beginning of the view.php.

```
<?php
session_start();
if ( ! isset($_SESSION['who']) ) {
    die('Not logged in');
}
require_once "pdo.php";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>123</title>
<?php require_once "bootstrap.php"; ?>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h1>Tracking Autos for <?php ?> </h1>
<h2>Automobiles</h2>
<p><a href="add.php">Add New</a> | <a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```